# Which network library does follow android guidelines?

Tags: android

I've seen a Google I/O 2012 talk on optimizing network performance and also read an article here : http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html.

Is there some network library that follows these guidelines? It should probably support some prefetching/caching and all those things described in the article above.

Comment: it actually is your 6th question.

Comment: they were quite outdated and neither of them has the actual answer to accept. anyway, accepted a couple that were closest, if that realy matters that much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RakNet](http://www.raknet.com/index.html).

Its a cross platform networking library. Under pricing android is listed as well, so I suppose it is supported. This library is well designed and since there is a pricing model for ios and  android i'm pretty sure it follows your mentioned guidelines

Comment: I will be happy enough with android-only library, paying for some cross-platform solution is not an option on my current project.

Comment: Indy license is free for first platform